# Why can my PC not use 15Hz of my monitor?

Tags: display, graphics-card, hdmi

I've bought a Lenovo L27q-30 2560 x 1440p 75Hz monitor.

On my PC that runs a i5-11400 (UHD 730 integrated graphics), it only shows the option to operate at 60Hz.

Yet, using the same HDMI cable and monitor with my crappy laptop - I can get 75Hz.

I've tried using both the latest drivers and the motherboard's offical drivers (MSI B560M Pro).

How can I fix this?